# Rundeck Automatic Login

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to configure rundeck OSS to automatically login? We currently have it configured to authenticate against Active Directory by setting all the JAAS related environments variables (RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_PROVIDERURL, RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_USERBASEDN, etc.) as described in https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/docker.html#basic

We're moving away from AD and standing up GCP IAP in front of it for the authentication. Since we aren't running Enterprise version, we can do SSO with GCP creds. So instead I'd just like to disable user authentication at the rundeck level altogether and have anyone who hits the URL to be logged in automatically. Only authenticated users at the IAP level should be able to hit the URL.

But I'm not seeing anything in the rundeck configs that allows automatic login. If anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's called preauth mode, basically is to put Rundeck behind a web server to pass user/roles headers from your application to Rundeck. [Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#preauthenticated-mode-using-headers) a explanation and [here](https://devopstales.github.io/sso/rundeck-sso/) you can see a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I've spent quite a while going down the preauth mode path and have not been able to get that working using GCP credentials or IAP credentials. Rundeck Support has told me they don't have any working examples of preauth with those and they weren't able to get it working.

So now I'm just trying to find a way to remove the authentication altogether from Rundeck and rely solely on IAP for authentication since it stands in front of Rundeck.